# Flask application Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Cannot be loaded as a python module

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a flask application to elastic beanstalk and I get a 500 error when I try to access it. I get the following trace from the error log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=19748): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160095 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160] mod_wsgi (pid=19748): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160187 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160228 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 107, in <module>
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160232 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]     @application.route("/signwriteragreement", methods=["POST"])
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160238 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1250, in decorator
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160241 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]     self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160246 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160248 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160253 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160256 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160]     'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
[Sat Jun 30 20:39:26.160268 2018] [:error] [pid 19748] [remote 172.31.2.189:31160] AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: signwriteragreement
```

My application has the following format:

```
application.py
config.py
helpers.py
emailsupport.py
models.py
search.py
requirements.txt
/docs
    (folders for saving documents)
/static
    (static files)
/templates
    (templates)
```

I did remember to call my application variable "application" so that's not the issue.

Here's the beginning of application.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, g, jsonify, render_template_string, send_from_directory, abort, Markup

application = Flask(__name__)
application.secret_key = "xxx"

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(application)

from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


csrf = CSRFProtect(application)
csrf.init_app(application)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/mnt/c/flasktest/repos/flasktestbackup/docs"
SHARED_FOLDER = UPLOAD_FOLDER + "/shared"

application.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql+pymysql://xxx:xxx@xxx.cc8l5tq11szj.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/xxx"

# ... (some other config stuff)... then

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            return redirect("/welcome")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

@application.route("/signwriteragreement", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def signwriteragreement():
    # rest of function
```

and at the bottom I have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: Did you perhaps have a prior error which you corrected the code for, but didn't restart Apache? Try restarting Apache and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: facing same error, any luck so far ?

Comment: @Vineet I got it to work! What was happening was I was running flask with "flask run" on my command line, but Amazon EB uses python application.py to run it. So I had to restructure my application so it would run with the python call instead of the flask command.

Comment: @Luke, I am still struggling with It, So I have created an Pandas related prediction which takes data from an excel file, I am using Windows machine where I created an virtual environment, installed all packages in virtual environment and its running fine on local machine but when I do 'eb deploy' and want to run the same application on EB then its not loading application.py as module and not able to use Pandas, Its working fine for sample application when I don't import pandas, Please help

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697160/deploying-flask-app-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/59698882#59698882