# Deploying Flask App in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

when I deploy my flask app, it says successful but when I retrieve the logs, I see the error "Flask not found". I have flask in my requirements file. Any help.

[Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.503908 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3393): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.503953 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3393): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.

[Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.504123 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last): [Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.504151 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 1, in 
[Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.504156 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from flask import Flask

[Sat Jan 11 06:51:50.504170 2020] [:error] [pid 3393] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'.

Below is my application.py content

```
from flask import Flask
from myapp import create_app

application = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Below is the content of my requirements.txt

```
Click==7.0
-e git+https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxx.git@xxxx#egg=xxx
Flask==1.1.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.1
PyYAML==3.13
scipy==1.4.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

Comment: Can you share your requirements.txt

Comment: Added the content of my requirements.txt

Comment: What's your python version

Comment: I am using python 3.6.8. However, there is one more warning about mod_wsgi being compiled for 3.6.2 and runtime python being 3.6.8. But that shouldnt be a problem as it was a warning and not an error.

Comment: i tried to simulate the same modules and version. it works fine with same python module versions. the only difference between yours and mine is  the `Click==7.0` where you are pointing to a git repository.

Comment: Strange. Because I removed the private git repository (not the Click) reference in my requirements.txt, it still didnt work.

Comment: just now i did a full end to end deployment of a basic flask app to elastic beans talk. my recommendation is, ssh into the machine and try to import Flask in the python console.

Comment: are you sure that you have the requirements.txt getting deployed, you can download the deployed zip and check

Comment: How do you download the deployed zip ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205827/discussion-between-arun-k-and-user3873617).

Comment: Goto Elastic beans talk console => select the app => select the application versions on the left , it should show you the link to download the zip file

Comment: Instead of using eb-cli, I used the eb web console and uploaded the zip file, strangely it worked.... Thank you for helping. I appreciate it.

Comment: glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You should have `application.py` and the `requirements.txt` at the root of the folder. Your deployed zip file also should contain these two files at the root of the zip file. I have attached the reference shows how to download a deployed application bundle.

Reference:
[Download a application from AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234574/download-a-application-from-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

can you try renaming the Flask object that you run to 'application':

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)
# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

From the Amazon EB Docs:

> Using application.py as the filename and providing a callable
>   application object (the Flask object, in this case) allows AWS Elastic
>   Beanstalk to easily find your application's code.

Comment: I added the content of my application.py in my original post.